# LaTeX Error: File 'image.jpg' not found

Tags: graphics, errors

I'm writing a thesis, and I want to insert images in the document. However, when I tried to use the command `\includegraphics` for the insertion of an image, the program gave me an error. I tried a lot of things, but all ended with an error.

In particular, I tried the following test configuration. On the desktop I created a main folder called "TestLatex", inside of which I created a subfolder called "Figures" and where the image "Pencils.jpg" is located. Then I wrote the following code and saved it as "Test.tex" in the main folder:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}      
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./Figures/} }
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{Pencils}
\end{document}
```

When I tried to compile the file, it gave me the following error:

```
Undefined control sequence. \includegraphics{Pencils}
! LaTeX Error: File `Pencils' not found.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              
l.5     \includegraphics{Pencils}                             
I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
[1{C:/Users/maxim/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}
] (Test.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
1443 strings out of 492895
20377 string characters out of 3133479
81682 words of memory out of 3000000
5366 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
3993 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
41i,4n,25p,273b,141s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on Test.pdf (1 page, 12128 bytes).
PDF statistics:
10 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

I tried also to copy-paste the image file from the subfolder to the main folder and the use the following code, but it resulted in the same error.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}      
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{Pencils.jpg}
\end{document}
```

**Summary:** From the conducted test, it seems that the original image inserting problem found in the thesis wasn't due to something related to the thesis document itself, but, from what I can deduce, to something strange in the program. Any ideas?

Comment: you seem to have edited the log `Undefined control sequence. '\includegraphics{Pencils}` is not the form of an undefined control sequence error. what command was undefined?

Comment: From the register file it says "Undefined control sequence. \includegraphics{Pencils}", from the issues report it says "! Undefined control sequence.
\Ginclude@graphics ...\Ginput@path \set@curr@file 
                                          {#1}\edef \uq@curr@file {\...
l.5  \includegraphics{Pencils}
                              
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined."

Comment: it would be better to show that in a code block as the line breaks are important but the command before the line break will be `\set@curr@file` which means that your graphics package is newer than your latex format, which (as always in miktex) probably means that you need to update _both_ user and admin mode to get your implementations back in sync.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "register file" that is not a tex output, is this something shown by your editor? If you are using texstudio please comment at https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/1068/

Comment: This is the link to a dropbox folder where I saved the screenshots of the errors. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/x2cnx4gsb5ne6jp/AAA5SjqBOXZ_sGNANGIjwGdva?dl=0

Comment: So it is texstudio please leave a comment at their bug site, it really is time they stopped confusing people by mangling the errors that latex reports.

Comment: How do I update both the user and admin mode of tex studio? I need to solve this problem as quick as possible.

Comment: texstudio is just your editor you need to update miktex (I do not use miktex so I can not give details)

Comment: I just updated MikTeK in both user and admin mode, and now the code works, for the test file and for the thesis file. Thank you very much!